# AWS ALB: Listener rules do not find static resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I created a application load balancer and a HTTPS listener. Now I want to add a path rule into the HTTPS listener rules. When I add the following path (rule priority 1): 
    `/Staging_app*` 
and when I call 
    `[Load Balancer URL]/Staging_app/index.html`
it returns the index page but I get for every static resource (like javascript files, css files, pictures) a 404 response. 
When I try to get the resources via:
    `[ECS Fargate Task dynamic IP]/resource.css`
I get the resources.

When I try to add the following rule entry:
    `Path is /Staging_app* OR /Staging_app/* OR /Staging_app`
I have the same problem.

The rule forwards to the ECS fargate service target group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not use the listener rules to manage all my apps with one ALB (not the way I wanted to do that).
When I configure a listener rule like this:
`/Staging_app*`
And when I call:
`[Load Balancer URL]/Staging_app/index.html`
I thought I get this files/resources: 
`/index.html`
`/resource.css`
But the request will not edited by AWS and AWS searches for:
`Staging_app/resource.css`
But this path does not exist.
This question helped me to understand my mistake: [How to tell AWS application load balancer to not forward the path pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39127115/7862824)